# Is it possible to create clusters in MapDB?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, scalable, mapdb

I have several questions regarding mapdb:

1. Can I configure clusters in mapdb?
   Because I didnt find any blogs about that so I guess it doesnt offer that
2. Several sources say that MapDB is scalable but what is exactly scalable? As far as I understand I simple integrate mapdb in maven and then I can use it but what do i scale exactly?

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK.   1)  No clusters.  2)  The scalability they are talking about is relative to classic Java collections.  Storage of data on disk means you are not limited by the heap size and garbage collection overheads. Aspects of the implementation mean that concurrency bottlenecks are reduced, and you can scale up the number of active threads, etc.

Comment: But if you are looking for something that will scale across multiple machines / application instances, this is probably not the right technology for you.